# Not able to open Firefox using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting an error when trying to open `Firefox` with `Selenium`. I tried this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile

profile = FirefoxProfile('/home/usr/.mozilla/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

The error was:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebdriverException: Message: Can't load the
profile. Profile Dir: '...../webdriver-py-profilecopy' If you specified 
a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Comment: You should set short issue description as title, not technology you use in your code or line of code

Comment: what are d versions of `firefox` and `selenium`?

Comment: What OS are you running? And what happens when you load without a profile set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using selenium 2.53.6

The issue is compatibility of firefox with selenium, since firefox>= 48 need Gecko Driver(https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver) to run testcases on firefox. or you can downgrade the firefox to 46..from this link https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0.1/

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://google.com')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.